# Filter a collection column by multiple values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection and I would like to filter it with one of the column contains multiple values. The filter values are dynamically generated and I dont know how many I will get.

I tried the following without success:

```
var input = @"was.Name.Contains(""Test"") ||  was.Name.Contains(""Test2"")";                             

var test = collection.Where(was => input)).ToList();
```

Comment: why not do it  `collection.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Test") || x.Contains("Test2")).ToList();`

Comment: See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how many parameters I will get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you receive the filter values as a CSV string:

```
var csvFilters = "Test1, Test2";
// split by ',', remove empty entries, 
// trim each filter and store the result in a list
var filters = csvFilters.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => x.Trim())
                        .ToList();

// return items in collection whose Name property
// is equal to any of the items in filters
var result = collection.Where(x => filters.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

This should translate to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM collection c 
WHERE c.Name IN ('Test1', 'Test2')
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use LINQ. The question is, how the "filter" values are kept? I'll answer in the way I understand your question.

If `input` is supposed to be a condition then I'd suggest using `Func<Object,bool>`. This means, the `input` would be the condition you're looking for, and if found, it would return `true`.

Here is a simple example:

```
IEnumerable <T> FindElements (Func<Object, bool> condition, IEnumerable<T> inputList)
{   
    List<T> outputList = new List<T>();
    foreach(var element in inputList)
    {
        if(condition != null && condition(element))
          outputList.Add(element);
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

Then, if you call the function given exemplary parameters:

```
string input[] = {"Test1","Test2"};
foreach(string s in input)
{
   targetList = FindElements(element=>((cast)element).Name.Contains(s), collection);
}
```

You should get all elements in `collection` which name has Test1 or Test2. Cast is of course name of the class which element instantiates.

Comment: Thank you. I dont need to use linq. If there is a better way please share

Comment: To be honest if you want to filter collections, LINQ is the best solution since it was invented for such purpose, I really encourage you to get familiarised with it. Even your pseudocode contains it.